# How to successfully compile this bootloader code?

Tags: assembly, loader, boot, masm

```
;------------------------------------------------------------
.286                               ; CPU type
;------------------------------------------------------------
.model TINY                 ; memory of model
;---------------------- EXTERNS -----------------------------
extrn               _BootMain:near     ; prototype of C 

func
;------------------------------------------------------------
;------------------------------------------------------------   
.code   
org             07x00h     ; for BootSector
main:
                jmp short start    ; go to main
                nop
                        
;----------------------- CODE SEGMENT -----------------------
start:  
        cli
        mov ax,cs               ; Setup segment registers
        mov ds,ax               ; Make DS correct
        mov es,ax               ; Make ES correct
        mov ss,ax               ; Make SS correct        
        mov bp,7c00h
        mov sp,7c00h            ; Setup a stack
        sti
                                ; start the program 
        call           _BootMain
        ret
        

END main                ; End of program
```

To be brutally honest I copied this code [from here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36907/How-to-develop-your-own-Boot-Loader).

I tried it myself but MASM does not agree. The only error I get is either:

```
StartPoint.asm(10) : error A2206: missing operator in expression
```

Or:

```
LINK : warning L4055: start address not equal to 0x100 for /TINY
```

Sorry if I made any mistakes asking this question, I'm new.

EDIT: The MASM version is 6.15 and I used ml StartBoot.asm in cmd. The syntax is ml [filename.asm].

EDIT: I intend to compile this into an .exe file.

Comment: You should supply the exact MASM version and the exact command line arguments you used.

Comment: there is a typo in `org 07x00h`

Comment: I fixed the typo but it still doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: I intend to compile this into an .exe file.**

An EXE file and even a COM file necessarily means that an OS exists to execute the program. Since you are writing a bootloader there will be no OS to rely on! A bootloader is just a piece of sofware that needs no special attention to run.

```
org             07x00h
```

This obviously is the line that MASM doesn't diggest. Change it to `org 7C00h`

Comment: I tried doing that but I still get the same "LINK : warning L4055: start address not equal to 0x100 for /TINY" error.

Comment: You need to compile using the **/AT** switch. The Original program at **codeproject.com** also used it! From the manual of Masm 6.15 we learn that this switch **Enables tiny-memory-model support. Enables error messages for code constructs that violate the requirements for .com format files. Note that this is not equivalent to the .MODEL TINY directive.**

Answer (score -1):

I'm not commenting on your code, but just on the error messages you cite. The assembler error is caused by a typo in the "org" directive (IIRC it should read 7c00h, not 7x00h), and the linker warning can safely be ignored: It points out that the resulting file will not work if invoked as ".com" DOS program. This does not matter, as you don't intend to do that.
You might encounter problems related to getting BootMain obey the correct conventions, and most likely you need to at least link StartPoint.obj first, but this is out of scope of the current question.

Comment: So how would I compile this into an executable (sorry for not mentioning it)

Comment: as user3144770 pointed out, the code you quote is not meant to be compiled into an .EXE file. It is meant to be put into the first sector of a floppy disk or hard drive partition to be executed by an IBM PC compatible BIOS. Furthermore, the linker message you quote is just a warning, so you should get an output file (which is, of course, not an .EXE or a .COM file, but just a binary blob to be written to a boot sector)